# get an error message "-bash: __rvm_clean_path: command not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, terminal, rvm

Just after I tried to develop a Rails project (version: 4.0.8), I start to receive this message.

Even when i start a new terminal tag, it will display on the very first line. Along with it, it has another message

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore "BLABLABLA DIRECTORY"'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
```

Why does this happen and how to solve it? Please!

Answer (score 1):

The `RVM used your Gemfile for ...` message is nothing to worry about. If it irks you, read it properly -- it should contain instructions for getting rid of it.

The other message : `-bash: __rvm_clean_path: command not found` is interesting. The thing is, the `__rvm_clean_path` function has been removed from the RVM source code long back. Try updating your RVM version by running

```
rvm get head
```

See if that fixes it. If not, respond here with the output of the following command:

```
rvm --version
```

Also share the content of the following files in your home directory:

1. `.bashrc`
2. `.bash_profile`
3. `.profile`